# Find names in ActiveWorkbook.Names

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find specific names in my workbook.names.

These names begin with "NameToFind" and the end of the names are ID numbers.

The goal is to find all ID.

```
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Left(n.Name, NameToFindLen) = NameToFind Then
        (...)
    end if
next n
```

I have a lot of names and this search is too long. How could I optimize this code?

Comment: If this works fine, and you're just asking to tips on improvement, I suggest instead posting to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BruceWayne It's quite stubby for Code Review though, to make a good fit it would need a whole lot of extra context. See the [help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: You could possibly use array instead.

Comment: Could you explain me how could an array improve a search in workbook.names please ? My code do only one loop through names, isn't it ?

Comment: Doesn't your code incorrectly match named cells where you have name1 and name12 ?... (as in the first parts match in both cases)

Comment: Also you can just do ActiveWorkbook.Names(NameToFind).Name for each of your names and catch errors

Comment: @CodyG. No, because the names I 'm searching are only with 3 digits at the end. Is there a way to improve this code ?

Comment: Yes, like I stated I think you can just do ActiveWorkbook.Names("NameOfName") and do a "try-catch" type of situation with VBA error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if this method is faster for you.
If you want to run this test case, add a named range "name1"
Then run test --- should show true in the immediate window.
If you haven't made the named range, should show false.

```
Option Explicit

Function IsName(NameOfName) As Boolean
    Dim check As Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Set check = ActiveWorkbook.Names(NameOfName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If check Is Nothing Then
        IsName = False
    Else
        IsName = True
    End If

End Function

Sub TestIsName()
    Dim test As Boolean
    test = IsName("name1")
    Debug.Print (test)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a little simpler solution

```
Function isName(NameofName) As Boolean

    Dim n As name
    isName = False
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If n.name = NameofName Then isName = True
        Exit Function ' not needed, but speeds up process for workbooks with a lot of names
    Next n
End Function
```